# TypeError in strptime in python 3.4

Tags: python

I have simple function like this

```
import datetime    
def myfun():
      string_date = '2016-11-03'
      myTime =datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

This gives an error

> TypeError attribute of type 'NoneType' is not callable
>   Error location: Unit: ".....\Test" Line: 4 Column: 1

this dose not happens if I close and open my IDE (TestComplete)

I am using python 3.4

What am'I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you have posted works normally, make sure the error is in these lines.

Comment: always show full error message (traceback). There can be more usefull information ie. line which makes problem.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. This code runs perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Does `datetime.datetime.strptime = ` appear anywhere in your code?

Comment: Error location: Unit: ".....\Test"
Line: 4 Column: 1. .......................I have only 4 lines in this script

Comment: If these are the only four lines in your script, than nothing will get called and no error should be raised. Don't worry about your post having too much code or too much information. It is better to show too much than to show not enough.

Comment: I'm running this using TestComplete as i mentioned in question.  dose testcomplea running this method makes something happens?

Comment: Are you doing some kind of assertion that expects the `function` object, but it's actually calling it (something like... `assert(fun, "foo")` vs. `assert(fun(), "foo")`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a bug in python 
https://bugs.python.org/issue27400

solution was

```
import datetime
import time

def myfun():
  string_date = "2016-11-03"
  format = "%Y-%m-%d"
  try:
      res = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, format)
  except TypeError:
      res = datetime.datetime(*(time.strptime(string_date, format)[0:6]))
  Log.Message(res) # testcompete print alternation
```

copied from TestComplete forum

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: function takes at most 8 arguments (9 given)" with your solution :(

Comment: Which python version you are in.? Are you sure the error doesn't fire from any other method in your code?

Comment: I've came across same issue with python 3.8 using Test Complete. According to attached link it supposed to be fixed